# Почему js код не работает в Safari или Opere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, opera

Есть некая функция в `js`  которая выводит на экран сообщения в таблицу(сообщения хранятся в `json`). В Google Chrome всё работает но вот Safari, Opera или Microsoft Edge?С чем это может быть связано?

```js
callback(
  [{
      "time": "1500303264",
      "user": "qwe",
      "message": "we",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "time": "1500303987",
      "user": "Max",
      "message": "q",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]);

function smile(mess){
var smile = ":)";
var graficSmile = "<img src = './image/Smile.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>";
var string_with_replaced_smile =  mess.replace(smile, graficSmile);

var sad = ":("
var graficSad = "<img src = './image/Sad.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>";
var string_with_replaced_smile_and_sad = string_with_replaced_smile.replace(sad, graficSad);

return string_with_replaced_smile_and_sad;
}

$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);
var exists = [];

function callback(respond) {
var timeNow = Date.now();

for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
 var data = respond[i];

 if (exists.indexOf(data.id) != -1) continue;

 var timeInMessage = data.time * 1000;
 var diff_time = (timeNow - timeInMessage);

 if(diff_time <= 3600000) {
  var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');
   
  var newDate = new Date(timeInMessage);
  var dateArray = [newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes(), newDate.getSeconds()]
  var res = dateArray.map(function (x) {
   return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
  }).join(":");

  $('#messages').append(rowClone);
  $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
  $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
  $('.message', rowClone).html(smile(data.message));
  $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height());

  exists.push(data.id);
 }
}
setTimeout(callback, 5000);
}
```

```css
.scroller {
  width: 490px;
  height: 255px;
  max-height: 255px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table#messages {
  min-height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

tr {
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
}

td.time,
td.name {
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

td.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form#text_submit {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input#text {
  width: 370px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #fffecd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

input#submit {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 21px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 95px;
  background: #635960;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<form method="POST" id="easyForm">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Вывод на экран сообщения сразу после ввода

```
function(arr) {
    arr = $.parseJSON(arr);

    var time = (arr.time);
    var date = new Date(+time * 1000);
    var d = new Date(date);

    var res = [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()].map(function (x) {
    return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
}).join(":");

$('#messages').append($('.mess_hide').clone().addClass('mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_hide'));
        $('.mess_tmp>.time').html(res);
        $('.mess_tmp>.name').html(arr.user);
        $('.mess_tmp>.message').html(smile(arr.message));
        $('.mess_tmp').removeClass('mess_tmp');
        $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height());

        $('#text').val('');
   }
```

`$.parseJSON(arr) : Object {time: "1500705673", user: "qwe", message: "w"}`

[image: Chrome]

[image: Opera]

Comment: @Yuri Сотрите обновленный вопрос.

Comment: А что именно не работает?

Comment: @Grundy Сам вывод на экран.

Comment: я вижу вызов `setTimeout(callback, 5000);`, в котором в callback ничего не предается, следовательно **в любом** браузере будет падать на строке `for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {` Так как `respond===undefined`

Comment: _Сам вывод на экран_ - есть ли ошибки в консоли при этом? Что имеется ввиду под _выводом на экран_?

Comment: @Grundy в консоли ничего нет. Имеется  ввиду что сообщения не загружаются из файла(насколько я понимаю) что бы вывестись на экран.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62360/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несомтря на описанную в комментариях проблему с `setTimeout`, ошибка возникает ещё до неё, с первым же вызовом `callback` в первой строчке кода:

```
callback(
  [{
      "time": "1500303264",
      "user": "qwe",
      "message": "we",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "time": "1500303987",
      "user": "Max",
      "message": "q",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]);
```

Внутри callback упоминается переменная `exists` и предполагается, что она - массив:

```
function callback(respond) {
...
    if (exists.indexOf(data.id) != -1) continue;
```

Она действительно определена в глобальной области видимости ввиду ["поднятия"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types) [определений](https://habrahabr.ru/post/127482/) наверх, но значение [] ей присваивается лишь позже, после вызова `$.getJSON(...)`. Так что в момент первого вызова `callback` значение ей ещё не присвоено, и потому функция падает с ошибкой до запроса сообщений. Так что Хром неправ, это не должно было работать.

Решение: перенести `var exists = [];` выше первого вызова `callback`.

Теперь ко второй проблеме. Тут всё просто, callback вызывается по таймеру, а когда он вызывается по таймеру, ему ничего не передаётся. Логично предположить, что на самом деле по таймеру требуется перечитывать файл с сообщениями data/messages.json и выводить уже его.

Решение: вместо `setTimeout(callback, 5000);` написать `setTimeout(function(){$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);}, 5000);`

Comment: Шикарный ответ, всё чётко и ясно! Спасибо большое!Есть один маленький вопрос когда я ввожу и оправляю сообщение оно сразу выводится на экран, а потом по вызову `callback` выводится ещё раз, как это можно исправить?(Вывод на экран добавил в вопрос).

Comment: @МаксимБуяков `callback` заносит в массив `exists` id обработанных сообщений, а при ручном добавлении id заранее неизвестен (полагаю, он создаётся на сервере), поэтому callback не останавливается и выводит их ещё раз. Идеального решения тут уже нет; но мне кажется незатратным такой способ: хранить несколько своих введённых сообщений в отдельном массиве "своих", в `callback` проверять их наличие по содержимому или таймстампам, и, соответственно, не выводить второй раз (но запоминать id в `exists` и удалять из "своих" во имя эффективности)